# Troubleshooting 'Notebook validation failed: data.cells' error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

How to resolve the error "Notebook validation failed: data.cells[{data__cells_x}] must be valid exactly by one definition (0 matches found)" in Jupyter Notebook?

How can I resolve the "Notebook validation failed: `data.cells[{data__cells_x}] must be valid exactly by one definition (0 matches found)`" error that occurs when opening a Python file in Jupyter Notebook? Additionally, when attempting to save the file, I receive the error message "The save operation succeeded, but the notebook does not appear to be valid. The validation error was: Notebook validation failed: `data.cells[{data__cells_x}] must be valid exactly by one definition (0 matches found): "<UNKNOWN>"`. What steps should I take to troubleshoot and rectify this issue, ensuring the notebook's validity and successful saving?